# MathPSFrag, Bounding box

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have been trying to use the MathPSFrag package to get a some of those super sweet figures we are all dreaming about. In running the MathPSFrag-Test.nb I pass all the test but trying a simple plot and export it via the following .nb it crashes

```
Needs["MathPSfrag`"];

myplot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True]

PSfragExport["myfilename", myplot] // UnPSfrag


StringForm::sfq: "Unmatched backquote in "`Could not determine bounding box from file `1` in directory `2`. I intentionally did not clean up temporary files, which will have to be removed manually."

UnPSfrag::bboxfailed: `Could not determine bounding box from file `1` in directory `2`. I intentionally did not clean up temporary files, which will have to be removed manually.

$Aborted
```

The input eps for the psfrag looks nice, but after I run the psfrag commands and look at the output eps file (unfragged in terms of the MathPSFrag terminology) Do any of you guys have any suggestion on how I can make this boundary box bigger? All help is appreciated.

Comment: You would have to provide more details regarding the actual plot. Edit your original question with a link to your *minimal* `.nb` file. Regardless, not sure whether this question is on-topic.

Comment: Most of the figures that I was dreaming about is now possible with `pgfplots` package. So you might wish to [read the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).